# Sent SMS message is automatically written to the content provider while it shouldn't in Cyanogenmod KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, cyanogenmod

From android KitKat when my application is set as the default one, sent sms messages should not be written to the content provider by system:

> Note: Beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), if and only if an app is not selected as the default SMS app, the system automatically writes messages sent using this method to the SMS Provider (the default SMS app is always responsible for writing its sent messages to the SMS Provider). For information about how to behave as the default SMS app, see Telephony.

But every message I send is automatically written without my interaction (I just call sendTextMessage() and it's taken care of)

May it be a bug in CyanogenMod or I am missing something?

Here is my Code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void sendMessage(String messageBody, String phoneNumber,
        Context context) {
    if (messageBody.length() > 0 && phoneNumber.length() > 0) {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(messageBody);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        if (prefs.getBoolean(SettingsActivity.KEY_SPLIT, false)) {
            for (String singlePart : parts) {
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, singlePart, null,
                        null);
            }
        } else {
            sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null,
                    null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add message to content provider (after KitKat)
     */
    // if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
    // android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    // Log.d(null, "adding sms to content provider");
    // ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    // values.put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, phoneNumber);
    // values.put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, messageBody);
    // // values.put(Telephony.Sms.READ, 0);
    // values.put(Telephony.Sms.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
    // // values.put(Telephony.Sms._ID,
    // // msgs[i].getIndexOnIcc());
    // context.getContentResolver().insert(Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI,
    // values);
    // }
}
```

Comment: It may very well be an issue with CyanogenMod, but we'd have to see your code to be certain.

Comment: If that code, while running on KitKat with the write-block commented out, still writes automatically, then yes, I would say it's a bug with CyanogenMod.

Comment: But how it is possible that other apps work properly? They probably also put the code to add sms to the provider and in every sms app they should be doubled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but when I added sent and delivered pending intent new sms is not automatically added to content provider. This solved my problem

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, singlePart, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Code from this question: [Trouble with sendMultipartText in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137836/trouble-with-sendmultiparttext-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same bug in my app on two devices. All with custom roms (CM based).
Try to use this library [android smsmms sending library](https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms) and if the issue persists, it may mean that there is something wrong with your manifest file.